# C Program Prints Unexpected Word. How does this happen?

Tags: c, arrays, floating-point, return, puts

Does anybody know how this works?

**C Program Source:**

```
int main ()
{
    float b[] = {1.143139e+27};
    puts(b);

    return 0;
}
```

**Output:**

```
Fell
```

Why would this program display "Fell"?

Comment: float `1.143139e+27` = hex `46656C6C` = ascii `Fell`

Comment: Use of implementation-defined aspects which may very well result in undefined behaviour... This question is invalid.

Comment: undefined behavior. no one knows when the string stops after those 4 bytes

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It has to do with the byte representation of `1.143139e+27`, which is exactly `Fell`, but without the terminating `nul` byte.

You can do the reverse process, like

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char b[] = {'F', 'e', 'l', 'l'};
    fprintf(stdout, "%g\n", *(float *)b);

    return 0;
}
```

and even add a terminating `nul` byte,

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char b[] = {'F', 'e', 'l', 'l', '\0'};
    fprintf(stdout, "%g\n", *(float *)b);

    return 0;
}
```

which means that changing `float b[] = {1.143139e+27};`, to `float b[] = {1.14314e+27};`

Comment: it might not work because `b` is not guaranteed to be aligned appropriately.

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc true, but I think the point is to explain why it does work when it works.